# Reading 2-dimensional array data from text file

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing

I know this question has been asked before on here, but I couldn't find anything that really helped me understand the problem.

I have a text filled called `input.txt`, which contents look something along the lines of:

```
4 4
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0
13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0
```

Where the first line determines the dimensions of the 2D array.

So using `fstream` I've found how to pull the strings from the file line by line, but my issue is with pulling the individual data out. I've tried using `substr` and found that that becomes a real headache when you are dealing with doubles that could possibly have a variable amount of decimal places.

Similarly, since this is for an introductory programming course, vectors are disallowed which is what I've normally used for such a thing (actually the reason I have to redo the assignment).

So using C-style arrays, how should I pull this info from `input.txt`?

My code for pulling from the first line:

```cpp
int m, n;
if (inputFile.good()) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(inputFile, line);

    std::string sizeX = line.substr(0, 1);
    std::string sizeY = line.substr(2, 1);

    m = stoi(sizeX);
    n = stoi(sizeY);
}
```

But this *also* would not work if the dimensions of the array were larger than 9.

So how can I improve both my first method, and subsequently pulling the remainder of the data into a C-style array for manipulation in memory.

Additionally, the token based methods I've seen, such as:

```cpp
int a, b;
while (infile >> a >> b)
{
    // process pair (a,b)
}
```

does not explain how you could do this for a variable number of elements per line.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use istringstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `>>` in a loop. It will make life much more complex if you want to read a line at a time, using `>>` will skip all whitespace including spaces and newlines.

```
ifstream infile("input.txt");
int size;
infile >> size;
double **arr = ... // allocate array based on size
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        infile >> arr[i][j];
```

I've assumed you know how to allocate the C style array. And I've also done no error checking which in a real program you should include. But hopefully I've illustrated how to read values into an array.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Trying to mess with strings and push them into doubles and substrings and delimeters and tokens, and blah blah blah. So thank you. This appears to be the perfect, simple solution I've been looking for.

Comment: @satazero I've just realised your input has has both dimensions of the array. But hopefully that's an easy change.

Comment: don't worry, I figured that part out on my own. `inputFile >> m >> n;` if anyone needs that tid bit of info.